# Android Gallery and Music empty?

Tags: music, gallery, htc-one-s

I recently discovered that all my photos on my phone has disappeared from the Gallery application. I connected my phone to my computer, and the images are still present in `DCIM/100MEDIA/` directory.

I did a backup of my photos, tried stopping the phone, the app (gallery), removing the cache from that app but no luck.

While searching for a solution online, I found that some people also had the same problem with the music app. I have albums that used to work, so I was sure to find them. But now they also have disappeared.

So Gallery and Music is empty despite having files in the correct folder.

Regarding Gallery, if I take a new photo, it will correctly be added to the `DCIM/100MEDIA/` folder, with the name `IMAG001332.jpg` (for example), but with `1332` being a correct incremental number (not starting from 0), which is even weirder.

I don't know what to do to fix it! Does anyone can help me?

(Note: I have an HTC One S)

Update: I did a reset of my phone (http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one-s-t-mobile/howto/315367.html) without any luck.

Comment: When you did the reset of your phone, did you clear data as well? If not I suggest doing that. Is there another app that might be conflicting with the gallery or music apps?